# Run SLN file (visual studio solution) from win form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a list of solutions items in ContextMenuStrip and I want to run selected one.

I have a mouse event set and I have the full path of the directory + file name.

I want to run the file and that will open it on visual studio.

I tried to use the action of

```
Process.Start(pathAndFileName);
```

when the pathAndFileName = D:\Code\MyRepoName\Solutions\TEST\TEST_1.sln

this will open the windows 10 select program to run for file
and Visual Studio is not in the list, but yet is set to be default for this files.

```
private void ContextMenuStrip2_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string pathAndFileName = ((ToolStripMenuItem)e.ClickedItem).ToString();
    Process.Start(pathAndFileName);
}
```

[run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wl7L.png)

Comment: Do you want to open the solution in VS, or compile and run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to start Visual Studio (devenv.exe) and supply the solution as a parameter, for example:

```
devenv.exe path\to\your\solution.sln
```

Comment: UseShellExecute should take care of that.